# Which music players support search by "Album Artist"?

Tags: music-player

All the music players I've tried have search by artist/album/genre but I really want search by "Album Artist".
Do any of the market players do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Music PlayerPro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/music-playerpro/com.tbig.playerpro) has that feature.

[image: QR Code]

But it's a Paid app. I tried many free ones, (powerAmp, winamp, cube, double twist, mixzing...) none have that feature!

Note 1: [Meridian](http://www.appbrain.com/app/meridian-media-player-hermit/org.iii.romulus.meridian) (free) can search using composers (it calls it writers).

Note 2: There is an issue-ticket related to this open in the [android issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2397). So this may be fixed in stock players in future.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed in the last few years, but you can no longer browse nor search by album artist in PlayerPro.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but GoneMad works.
PowerAmp and PlayerPro do not.

Comment: Their Google Play page says you cannot browse by album artist, but you can search by album artist. Having said that, I can't work out how to even do that!

Answer (score 1):

powerAmp isn't free, I guess you should give shazam a try, it's paid but it's one of the best, it even listens to music if there is any around you and try to recognize giving you the track name, artist,.... etc, also it searches by album artist.

Comment: PowerAmp won't let you browse or search by album artist. You can browse by "Albums by Artist", but this is lists all albums, which are then further split by artists (i.e. even worse!). Also, Shazam is not a music player, but (as you say) an application to identify music through your device's microphone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Rocket Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer) The free version's feature set is fairly comprehensive and to top that off, it respects its users by showing no advertisement.

When you install it, click the three dots icon at the bottom-right corner (or possibly bottom-left if you have a right-to-left language), and select Settings. From there, you can go to the "Tabs" menu and enable the "Album Artists" tab. You can also go to the "My Library" menu and select the conditions for album grouping (applied globally, but most notably you'll want this for the "Albums" tab). Obviously, you'll want to tick "Same album artist".